# Problem expanding macro in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a clojure macro:

```
(defmacro show
  [x] `(show-fn ~x)
)
```

: which given :

```
(show hello)
```

I want to resolve to :

```
(show-fn 'hello)
```

: How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user=> (defmacro show [x] `(~'show-fn '~x))
#'user/show
user=> (macroexpand '(show hello))
(show-fn (quote hello))
```

This is called 'symbol capture'. It keeps the symbol from being resolved in the current namespace, as with your example.

Comment: @Zubair Done. Note that it isn't going to actually expand to 'hello, because ' expands to quote. It's the same thing though.

Comment: You probably don't want to capture `show-fn` - it's usually better to let that one be syntax-quoted, like `(show-fn '~x)`.

Comment: He did for some reason. Not sure if you were responding to him or me. I was just answering the question rather than giving a lecture on why not to do it.